# Replace ( gsub) all rows in a column from values in another column?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe as such,

```
   df = data.frame ( a = c(1,14,15,11) , b= c("xxxchrxxx","xxxchryy","zzchrzz","aachraa") )
       a   b
    1  1 xxxchrxxx
    2 14 xxxchryy
    3 15 zzchrzz
    4 11 aachraa
```

what I want is to replace chr from column b with chrx, x derive from column a

```
   a   b
1  1 xxxchr1xxx
2 14 xxxchr14yy
3 15 zzchr15zz
4 11 aachr11aa
```

however I cant get gsub to work since its expecting a single element

```
df$b = gsub ( "chr",paste0("chr",df$a), df$b)
```

any way to do this?

Comment: just use `paste` `df$b <- with(df, paste0(b, a))`  Also, `replacement` in `gsub` take a vector of length 1 `?gsub` `if a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used with a warning.`

Comment: Also maybe: `df$b<-paste0(df$b,df$a)`

Comment: Sorry I should had made my example better but the problem is that I need to use gsub because the string in b can be complicated, like aaa.chr.xxx so that it needs to be explicity replaced?  I will edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `gsub` `replacement` takes only a vector with length 1.  According to `?gsub`

> replacement - if a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used with a warning.

If it needs to have a vectorized replacement, use `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(df$b, "chr", paste0("chr", df$a))
#[1] "xxxchr1xxx" "xxxchr14yy" "zzchr15zz"  "aachr11aa"
```

---

Based on the example, it is only a simple `paste`

```
df$b <- with(df, paste0(b, a))
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:: With `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(df$b,"chr",paste0("chr",df$a))
```

Continuing with `paste0`:

```
df$b<-paste0(df$b,df$a)
   a     b
1  1  chr1
2 14 chr14
3 15 chr15
4 11 chr11
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
df = data.frame ( a = c(1,14,15,11) , b= c("chr","chr","chr","chr") )
df$b <- paste0(df$b, df$a)
df
#>    a     b
#> 1  1  chr1
#> 2 14 chr14
#> 3 15 chr15
#> 4 11 chr11
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>